# TextInput placeholder style not work properly

Tags: react-native, placeholder, react-native-textinput

I'm having an issue when I try to custom my `TextInput` whereas the `placeholder` will have `normal` fontWeight and the textinput will be `bold`.

This is my code for that:

```
<TextInput
    placeholder={'Input'}
    style={{ width: '100%', fontWeight: this.state.text.length > 0 ? 'bold' : 'normal' }}
    value={this.state.text}
    onChangeText={(text) => {
           this.setState({
                 text,
             });
       }}
/>
```

My issue is: Firstly, placeholder have normal `fontWeight`, i entered some randomly input and then delete all of it, the placeholder style is not change back to normal but still be bold.

[image]

Comment: Try this: style={{ width: '100%', fontWeight: this.state.text.length === 0 ? 'normal' : 'bold' }} or you can also try style={{ width: '100%', fontWeight: this.state.text === "" ? 'normal' : 'bold' }}

Comment: @noobprogrammer tks for that. But that not work man :( I just update my screenshot for easier understand my issue.